# Thumbnail request for Excel spreadsheet returning an empty array

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

All other file types that I've tried (presentation, photo, and word document) are all returning full thumbnail arrays as expected. Is there a reason for this exceptional situation?

request being made to: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}/thumbnails`

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, we don't currently support thumbnails for Excel. Feel free to bring it up on the user voice forums:

https://office365.uservoice.com/